# How can I merge the values of a multidimensional array based on a single element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Given the following array, how do I get the distribution of years per state?

- The first array element is the state.
- The second array element is the count of elements *per state* in the array
- The third element is the year associated with the state

For example, look at Florida. There are 2 entries from 2021 and one from 2022.

```
[
    ["Arizona", 1, 2021],
    ["California", 1, 2021],
    ["Florida", 3, 2021],
    ["Florida", 3, 2022],
    ["Florida", 3, 2021],
    ["Mississippi", 1, 2022],
    ["Ohio", 3, 2021],
    ["Ohio", 3, 2022],
    ["Ohio", 3, 2023],
]
```

The desired output array would collapse these matching entries

```
  ["Florida", 3, 2021],
```

with the total count remaining intact. Thus, 2 + 1 = 3.

```
  [
    ["Florida", 2, 2021],
    ["Florida", 1, 2022],
    ["Ohio", 1, 2021],
    ["Ohio", 1, 2022],
    ["Ohio", 1, 2023],
  ]
```

I've tried filtering, but to no avail. is this even possible giving the input?

I tries something like the following, but I have no idea how to proceed.

```
let filtered = postsSummary.filter((el) => el[3].includes(2021));

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Whatever attempts you've made should be added to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: I don't see any criteria that would actually remove "Arizona", "California", and "Mississippi", from the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second element of each tuple of the input data is just noise and can be ignored. While iterating, you need to maintain a KV cache of counts keyed by the combination of state-year:

```js
function transform (array) {
  const cache = {};

  for (const [state,, year] of array) {
    const key = JSON.stringify([state, year]);
    cache[key] = (cache[key] ?? 0) + 1;
  }

  return Object.entries(cache).map(([json, count]) => {
    const [state, year] = JSON.parse(json);
    return [state, count, year];
  })
}

const input = [
  ['Arizona', 1, 2021],
  ['California', 1, 2021],
  ['Florida', 3, 2021],
  ['Florida', 3, 2022],
  ['Florida', 3, 2021],
  ['Mississippi', 1, 2022],
  ['Ohio', 3, 2021],
  ['Ohio', 3, 2022],
  ['Ohio', 3, 2023],
];

const expected = [
  ['Arizona', 1, 2021],
  ['California', 1, 2021],
  ['Florida', 2, 2021],
  ['Florida', 1, 2022],
  ['Mississippi', 1, 2022],
  ['Ohio', 1, 2021],
  ['Ohio', 1, 2022],
  ['Ohio', 1, 2023],
];

function equalJson (a, b) {
  return JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b);
}

const actual = transform(input);

const equal = equalJson(actual, expected);
console.log('equal:', equal);
```

Comment: Great approach to packing/unpacking data into the object key!